# How to access an Access Tokem from a header in a REST Service with Spring?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I have a REST service that is used together with a client app. The client app gets a bearer token from an Auth Server. I want to use this token when my App sends a request to the REST service to identify the user.

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UifQ.xuEv8qrfXu424LZk8bVgr9MQJUIrp1rHcPyZw_KSsds" "http://localhost:8080/greeting"
```

The token contains infos on who is the user (see https://jwt.io/) in this case the name "John Doe".

Currently I got the following Controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/greeting/{name}"})
    public String greeting(@PathVariable String name, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        return String.format(template,name);
    }
}
```

Instead of the name in the path variable it should use the name from the bearer token and it should only do so if it's a valid token. My guess is there is a way to add a Configuration with spring security that checks if it's a valid token and then expose the information from the token to the controller.

I know I can access the token with `@RequestHeader("Authorization")` but I hope there is at least a way to verify the validity of the token before that (e.g. there will be a timestamp in the token to check if it is still valid).

Comment: To get the header value is trivial..., to "secure" this controller takes some more effort - [this article](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/) ..can serve as an entry point. [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) seems very up-to-date.